# info.plist settings for iPad only app

Tags: ios, ipad, info.plist

I want to submit an iPad only app through iTunes.  I have already made the following configuration changes.

- Under Summary, I have set the `Active Target Device : iPad`
- Under Build Settings, Valid Architectures is set to `armv7`

Although, this will ensure that the build doesn't run on non iPad devices, I want to also ensure that in App Store results, users do not see this app listed under iPhone Apps.

When reading the iOS developer portal documentation, Apple mentions that you must include the key `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` to indicate which devices this app is allowed to run on.

1. Is UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities the correct approach to ensure that my app only appears in iPad results?
2. What should its value be set to? armv7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the `Active Target Device : iPad` iPhone user will not see the app in the App Store on the device.

Since iPhone/iPod Touch cant run iPad app where as an iPad can run iPhone apps your app will not show up in the App Store on the device.